# Is there a limit to the number of objects that one material can be applied to?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have a file with lots of objects referring to the same image texture.

I have added a few more objects that use the same material and the new objects render black when using the Cycles engine - they also cause one of the original objects that was previously rendering fine to render black as well - if I remove the material from the new objects all of the original objects render fine.

If I apply a different material with a different image texture to the new objects they render as expected.

I am sure this is a simple newbie mistake but it's got me beaten and I have google around with no success.[[image: MaterialsPreview][1]]
[image]

I can't seem to get the file below 40Mb to use Blend-Exchange so I have put a version in dropbox (I hope this is acceptable) https://www.dropbox.com/s/k44ny1a5xxe4x0u/ECBCutdownPACKED1.blend?dl=0

Comment: what render engine do you use? does your material have transparency? glass node?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I would recommend to attach some screenshots of the viewport showing the objects with the material applied and eventually a rendered part showing the result. This way it would be easier to see what your talking about. Generally a material should not cause a problem if applied to many objects, so a visual would help point out a problem. Best case would be a redacted blend file, with only the problem parts. You can [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/190423/edit) your question and add that using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: You didn't pack your image into the file. From the Blender header menu: **File > External Data > Pack All to .blend.** This will pack all external data into your file

Comment: BTW that stick seems to not using the same material compare to other WoodPrank. It is a duplicated one which has `.001` as a postfix in material name